# error TypeError: (0 , _useIsomorphicLayoutEffect.useIsomorphicLayoutEffect) is not a function

Tags: redux, next.js

On configuring Redux with Next.js am getting this err
following is my package.json versions
   `"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.5", "next": "13.4.7", "react": "18.2.0", "react-dom": "18.2.0", "react-redux": "^8.1.1", "redux": "^4.2.1"`

tried to start next.js server locally by `npm run dev` . But UI showing err `error TypeError: (0 , _useIsomorphicLayoutEffect.useIsomorphicLayoutEffect) is not a function`

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You are likely trying to use a component (`Provider`) or hook that can only be used in a client component in a server component.

You can read up on that in the [Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials#third-party-packages)

Comment: got it, since i use a component (Provider) or hook that can only be used in a client component  **'use client'** need to be included in the file

Comment: Even though I added `'use client'` it did not help me. You can find more info [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/59090). Any idea?